# storing sections of text file into multiple dictionary entries based on location

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

Extreme beginner to python (somewhat new to coding). Searched around, got some helpful hints, but my particular case is a little more complicated than other related stackoverflow posts (that I could find at least).

I have a text file of results. Theres a particular part of the file where "Summary" is written and that's overall section I want to focus collection on. **After** the

```
Summary:
```

line, there are 5 **subsections**, which have their own data, that I want to store as keys in the dictionary. The subsections will be called, level1, level2,-->level5.

The beginning of each subsection has a line with only that subsection's name, i.e.

```
level1:
```

So, to summarize:
 Create a dictionary with 5 keys (labeled level1-->level5) that each have contain the line data from that subsection, but make sure that once the subsequent level is reached, to stop saving the data for the previous keys.

Here is what I have so far (WARNING: the following is extremely sloppy code and it might cause pain for more experienced coders):

```
results = sys.argv[1]
seen_start = False
seen_1 = False
seen_2 = False
seen_3 = False
seen_4 = False
seen_5 = False
results_matrix = {}
j = 'level1'
k = 'level2'
l = 'level3'
m = 'level4'
n = 'level5'

with open(results, "r") as f:

    for line in f:
        if line.find("Summary:") ==0:
            seen_start = True
            continue

        if seen_start:

            if line.find(j) ==0:
                seen_1 = True
                continue

            elif line.find(k) ==0:
                seen_1 = False
                seen_2 = True
                continue
            elif line.find(l) ==0:
                seen_2 = False
                seen_3 = True
                continue
            elif line.find(m) ==0:
                seen_3 = False
                seen_4 = True
                continue
            elif line.find(l) ==0:
                seen_4 = False
                seen_5 = True
                continue



        if seen_1 and line <> '\n':
            results_matrix[j] = (line.rstrip('\n'))
            if line.find(k) ==0:
                seen_1 = False
                seen_2 = True
                continue


        if seen_2 and line <> '\n' :
            results_matrix[k] = (line.rstrip('\n'))
            if line.find(l) ==0:
                seen_2 = False
                seen_3 = True
                continue
            print results_matrix[k]
```

---

Believe it or not, the code actually saves the latest subsection correctly, but saves the *previous* entries as the last line for that subsection. i.e. results_matrix[k] will work in this instance but results_matrix[j] has entries of only the last line for that section

---

Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: it's hard to say how to do this without an example.  Can you post the content of a text file you're trying to parse?

Comment: @xhainingx, James Thiele figured it out. I can still provide sample code if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results_matrix[j] = (line.rstrip('\n'))` rewrites `results_matrix[j]` on every line, so only the last line is seen. Try adding:
`results_matrix[j] = ""`

before the `for` loop then:
`results_matrix[j] = results_matrix[j] + line`

Using the `rstrip` will run all your lines together.